# Nativescript RadListView Header Disappearing (Android)

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am using RadListView trying to use the header feature. If I try to use a StackLayout inside the header it disappears after the content is loaded. But if the header is one element (such as a Label) it works fine. The issue only appears on Android.

```
<GridLayout>
        <RadListView [items]="products">
                <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                                <Label class="nameLabel" text="test title"></Label>
                                <Label class="descriptionLabel" text="test description"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template tkListViewHeader>
                        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                                <Label text="This is header row 1"></Label>
                                <Label text="This is header row 2"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
        </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Before Load:

[image]

After load:

[image]

Comment: Until you get a proper response: can you try to give the header a height of 100 for example?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue with same example from docs except using StackLayout for header view with 2 labels. Can you try creating a Playground example where we can see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. My data source for the list was not an Observable. So I guess it can't work with dynamic content being loaded directly into a normal array after it has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the height of the RadList Before loading any data